# Display strings from a list one by one into a label

Tags: c#, list, loops

I have a label. I have a list. when I do "label1.Text = match.Value;", it just displays the last item of the list, as opposed to 1 string that changes each time I click a button. The code is:

```
private void frontPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string url = "http://reddit.com/r/pics";
        var source = getSource(url);
        var regex = new Regex([regex removed]);
        var links = new List<string>();
        var titles = new List<string>();

        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(source))
        {
            links.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
            titles.Add(match.Groups[2].Value);

        }

        foreach (var title in titles)
        {
            label1.Text = title; /*it just shows the last 'title' in 'titles', I want it to start at the first, and go to the next title every time the event occurs (frontPageToolStripMenuItem_Click)*/ 
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: titles should be a global var, you should build it when you load the form. In the click event handler you should only move the titles to the next value.

Comment: All your code is executed at once. There is no reason for `foreach` loops to proceed only by one element for each button click, so why should they? Instead, they iterate over the whole enumeration, hence the last element remains. If you want to proceed step by step, you'll have to save the current progress somewhere *outside* of your method.

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize the list outside of your click event handler. You could create an `FetchImageData` method that is called when your program starts (perhaps call it from the constructor of your class). Or you could call it the list the first time the click event is fired.

```
private int clickCounter = 0;
private List<string> links;
private List<string> titles;

private void FetchImageData()
{
    links = new List<string>();
    titles = new List<string>();

    const string url = "http://reddit.com/r/pics";
    var source = getSource(url);
    var regex = new Regex([regex removed]);

    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(source))
    {
        links.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
        titles.Add(match.Groups[2].Value);
    }
}
```

You haven't said what should happen when the user clicks more times than there are elements. One option is to wrap around and starts again from the beginning. This can be achieved using the `%` operator.

```
private void frontPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (titles == null) { FetchImageData(); }
    label1.Text = titles[clickCounter % titles.Count];
    clickCounter++;
}
```

Comment: +1 modulo is a very nice solution. I think only check for count > 0 is needed.

Comment: @MarkByers: Already +1'ed and removed my comment as it doesn't apply any more.

Answer (score 0):

UI thread doesn't get a chance to update the label because your for loop is on the UI thread. Even if you move the for loop to a background thread good chance  you 'll only see some flickering and then the final string. Just append the strings to a textbox or output them using Debug.writeLine. This will show you that you are reading the correct strings.

To change the label just once don't do it in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

1) `titles` should be global variable

2) Move this in the constructor of the form

```
    const string url = "http://reddit.com/r/pics";
                var source = getSource(url);
                var regex = new Regex("<a class=\"title \" href=\"(.*?)\" >(.*?)<");

        titles = new List<string>();

                foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(source))
                {
                    links.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
                    titles.Add(match.Groups[2].Value);

                }
label1.Text = first value of the titles
```

3) Your event handler should be like this:

```
private void frontPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            label1.Text = next value of the titles variable;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Second **`foreach`** loop put **`label1.Text += title;`** instead of **`label1.Text = title;`** then it will work fine.